# How can I reference the Default VPC in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a stack which needs resources which need to be deployed in a certain VPC. I want to use the default VPC but I don't want to parameterize this. Is there a way to automatically obtain the default VPC value? (Like for example `Fn::GetAZs: region` for AZ's in a region).

Comment: I've seen situations where _not_ referring to a specific VPC results in use of the Default VPC. Can you edit your question to include a template snippet showing the resource you wish to create in the default VPC?

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Some resources require explicit specification of VPC ID. One example is [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-vpcid)

Answer (score 7):

The ID of the default VPC can be obtained using the following AWS CLI command:

```sh
$ aws ec2 describe-vpcs \
    --filters Name=isDefault,Values=true \
    --query 'Vpcs[*].VpcId' \
    --output text

vpc-a1b2c3d4
```

The above command will output something like: `vpc-a1b2c3d4`

You can assign this output to a variable and then pass it to your CF template like this:

```
$ default_vpc_id=$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs \
    --filters Name=isDefault,Values=true \
    --query 'Vpcs[*].VpcId' \
    --output text)

$ echo ${default_vpc_id}

vpc-a1b2c3d4
```

Comment: That's not the answer to the question because it is explicetly saying it doesn't want to parameterize this

Comment: @TomasG There is no other way unless you want to develop your own custom resource to get the default VPC Id.

Comment: @Marcin then imo that should be the answer